# How update item in List with Map in DynamoDb?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-php-sdk

I have a problem, how write item in `conditionExpression`?

```
$item = [
    'id' => ['N' => '382'], 
    // List of Maps
    'phone' => ['L' => [
        ['M' => [
            'type'   => ['S' => 'home'],
            'number' => ['S' => '5555555555'],
        ]],
        ['M' => [
            'type'   => ['S' => 'mobile'],
            'number' => ['S' => '66666666'],
        ]],
    ]],
];

$mass = [
   ":number" =>''66666666',
];
$eav = $marshaler->marshalJson(json_encode($mass,true));
$params = [
....
'ConditionExpression' => ' phone[1].number = :number',
'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $eav,
];
dynamoDb->updateItem($params);
```

`phone[0].number` doesn't work. How do I refer to the element?